# Bash - shell vs environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I want to clarify a confusion I am having in shell variable vs environment variable. I did the following test, where I have a shell variable `abc` and `export` it to an environment variable.

```
$ 
$ abc="shell var"
$ env | grep abc
$ echo $abc
shell var
$ export abc="env var"
$ env | grep abc
abc=env var
$ echo $abc
env var
$ unset abc
$ env | grep abc
$ echo $abc
$
```

After the export is done, I try to `echo $abc`.

Questions:

- Does export move the variable `abc` from shell to the environment OR does it create a copy in the environment and assign it a new value ?
- When the second `echo` is done after the `export`, does `echo` check if `abc` is in environment and then print it, OR has `abc` been completely removed from the shell and is only present in the environment which is why `echo` prints its value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does export move the variable abc from shell to the environment OR does it create a copy in the environment and assign it a new value ?

Neither.  `export` simply marks a variable for export.

When an external command is executed, the shell creates an environment to pass to it.  Only variables marked for export are added to that environment.  As `man bash` explains:

> shell variables and functions marked for export, along with variables exported for the command, [are] passed in the environment

Note that `env` is an *external* command.  Consequently, it can only report on variables that have been exported.

#### Meaning of "variables exported for the command"

Normal variable assignments have persistence: the variable exists until it is removed (unset).  It is also possible to created temporary variables for use by a particular command.

As an example, let's create a variable `a` for use by the `env` command:

```
$ a=b env | grep ^a=
a=b
```

Comment: What does "variables exported for the command" mean ? How are they different from the variables marked for export ? Thanks.

Comment: Also: when I do `export abc="env var"`, does that mean : change the value for this shell variable, but also mark this for export ? I guess that's why `echo $abc` prints `env var` still being in the shell process ?

Comment: @Jake Yes, `export abc="env var"` does the assignment and marks the variable for export all in one step.  Also, I added to the answer an example of a "variable exported for the command."

Comment: I had another question. When a command is run in bash, some environment variables will be given to the new process by default - where are all these environment variable (like SHELL) marked for export ? (Let me know if I should a new question for this)

Comment: @Jake Unlike user variables, the variable `SHELL` is  managed directly by the shell.  The shell manages many such variables.  For a full list of shell such variables set by bash, look in `man bash` for the section entitled "Shell Variables".

Comment: I asked a related question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222939/63934. Thank you for your time !