# Bash - check environment variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables

The `env` command can be used to print environment variables in bash. I want to ask if there is any built-in command to do this ?

```
$ export temp="hello world"
$ env | grep temp
```

The second command will indeed print `temp's` value, but that's because it is inherited as environment when `env` was spawned. I want to check what environment variables the bash shell process had originally, in which `temp` would still not be part of environment , but just marked to be exported as environment for any child (I want to test this).

Comment: Have you tried `set` ?

Comment: try `set -o posix; set`

Comment: @gwillie: It will show the exported variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. When exporting or declaring a variable inside a shell, the variable is **not** added to the shell's environment (in the mean of updating the file - read below).

You can view the environment variable the shell (or any other process) had when it was invoked on Linux by viewing the file `/proc/PID/environ`, where `PID` is the PID of the process you want to analyze. The variables are saved in the classic form `var=value` and are separated by the null character.

Comment: I have two shell scripts `cmdline` and `environ`, which just do `tr '\0' '\n' <<</proc/${pid}/cmdline` (figure out the second one).

Comment: Sorry, one `<` only instead of `<<<`.

Comment: `$$` has the shell's pid, so, `tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$$/environ`